# how to get bookmark page from crome browser and display in android app?

Tags: android

```
final String[] columns = { Browser.BookmarkColumns.TITLE, Browser.BookmarkColumns.URL };
Cursor query = getContentResolver().query(Browser.BOOKMARKS_URI,columns, null, null, null);
query.moveToFirst();
while (query.moveToNext()) {
String title = query.getString(query.getColumnIndex(Browser.BookmarkColumns.TITLE));
String url = query.getString(query.getColumnIndex(Browser.BookmarkColumns.URL));
Log.d("msg"," d  "+title+"  d "+url);
urlArray.add(url);
}
```

I have use this code but this code give me browser history i want to get only bookmark page url.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try This code,

**MainActivity.java :**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

private ArrayList<String> titles;
private ArrayList<String> urls;
private ArrayList<Bitmap> bitmaps;
private ContentResolver cr;
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    createLists();
}
protected void onResume(){
    super.onResume();
    getBH();
    showHistoryBookmarks();

}

public void createLists(){
    titles=new ArrayList<String>();
    urls=new ArrayList<String>();
    bitmaps=new ArrayList<Bitmap>();

}
public void getBH(){
    Bitmap icon;
    cr=getContentResolver();
    String order= Browser.BookmarkColumns.DATE+" DESC";
    String[] projection={Browser.BookmarkColumns.TITLE,Browser.BookmarkColumns.URL,Browser.BookmarkColumns.FAVICON};
    //String selection=projection[0]+"=?";
    //String args[]={"Google"};
    Cursor rows=cr.query(Browser.BOOKMARKS_URI,projection, null,null,order);
    if(rows.getCount()>0){
        while(rows.moveToNext()) {
            //read title
            String title=rows.getString(rows.getColumnIndex(projection[0]));
            //read url
            String url=rows.getString(rows.getColumnIndex(projection[1]));
            //read icon
            byte[] bicon=rows.getBlob(rows.getColumnIndex(projection[2]));
            if(bicon!=null){
                //convert blob image data to Bitmap
                icon=BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(bicon,0,bicon.length);

            }
            else{
                //default icon for history and bookmarks that do not icons
                icon=BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.star2);
            }
            //add to lists
            addToList(title,url,icon);
        }
        //close the cursor
        rows.close();
    }
}

public void getBrowserHist()  {
    Cursor mCur = managedQuery(Browser.BOOKMARKS_URI,
            Browser.HISTORY_PROJECTION, null, null, null);
    mCur.moveToFirst();
    if (mCur.moveToFirst() && mCur.getCount() > 0) {
        while (mCur.isAfterLast() == false) {
            Log.v("titleIdx", mCur
                    .getString(Browser.HISTORY_PROJECTION_TITLE_INDEX));
            Log.v("urlIdx", mCur
                    .getString(Browser.HISTORY_PROJECTION_URL_INDEX));
            mCur.moveToNext();
        }
    }
}


public void addToList(String title,String url, Bitmap bitmap){

    titles.add(title);
    urls.add(url);
    bitmaps.add(bitmap);

}


public void showHistoryBookmarks(){
    ListView l=(ListView) findViewById(R.id.hb_list);
    if(l!=null){
        if(titles.size()>0){
            ListAdapterModel aa=new ListAdapterModel(this,R.layout.listlayout,R.id.hbtitle,titles,urls,bitmaps);
            l.setAdapter(aa);
        }
        else{
            Toast.makeText(this, "This is no bookmark or history.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }

}

public void cleanHB(){
    if(Browser.canClearHistory(cr)){
        Browser.clearHistory(cr); //clear history data
        createLists(); //recreate the lists
        onResume(); //update the list
    }

}
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    //Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item){
    if(item.getItemId()==R.id.action_clean)
    {
        cleanHB();

    }
    return false;
}
```

}